# Execute a command when add a new file in folder

Tags: bash, executable

I am not sure weather it's possible or not. I am looking for a script/command that will execute a command or run a scripts when I will add a file in a folder.

For instance:

I am practicing bash scripting. After writing a bash script, I have to make my script file to a executable using this command `chmod +x filename.sh` . All my scripts has stored in a folder named BASH . So, when I add a new  `.sh` file in that folder, I want a command/script to run which will make my `.sh` file executable.

How to do it?

Comment: You *could* do it with a cron job, checking for new files every minute, but then there could be a delay of (max) a minute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `inotifywait`.  To apply `chmod +x` to every file written in directory BASH, keep the following script running:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=BASH
inotifywait -m "$dir" -e close_write --format '%w%f' |
    while IFS=' ' read -r fname
    do
        [ -f "$fname" ] && chmod +x "$fname"
    done
```

If you are curious, you can see all that `inotifywait` can tell about what is happening in directory bash by running:

```
inotifywait -m BASH
```

For more information, see `man inotifywait`.

To use `inotifywait`, you may first need to install `inotify-tools`: run `apt-get install inotify-tools`.

Comment: Thanks @John , How can make inotify script running. I have already created the script in my working folder. Do i need to run it using ./inotifyscript.sh this way?

Comment: Yes.  You can keep it running in one shell/terminal while you create files in other shells/terminals.  When you get the script adjusted to your satisfaction, you can run it in the background.

Comment: Yes, I got it and working great! Thanks again @John